# Issue accessing a webservice published in VirtualBox from mac

Tags: macos, web-services, virtualbox

I'm facing a problem trying to access a webservice published in a virtual machine created with VirtualBox.

I created a Web service in Visual Studio but I published the web service in IIS but I need to consume the Web service from my application in my MAC computer.

What I did?

1. I aggregate an Internal Network adapter and Bridge Network adapter.

The main adapter is NAT.
I checked with the ping command on my mac terminal with the IP: 192.168.0.16 and I got ping to the IP address but my service still inaccessible.

I will appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, the problem was the Firewall the windows in the virtual machine.